# NTP and iptables for time syncing within and across datacenter locations

Tags: iptables, firewall, ntp, synchronization

I have several linux (Debian) servers across two data centers located on the east and west coast of the US. I picked one server from each location to be a NTP server. The NTP server syncs time with the 0-3.us.pool.ntp.org servers. That seems to be working well so far.

The clients are configured to use ntp1 and ntp2. I set firewall rules (UDP 123) up on the clients.

My question is, how can I configure the servers so that clients can use both of my NTP servers  and prevent my NTP servers from being public time servers to everyone else?

I'm not sure how to configure the /etc/ntp.conf file on the servers to restrict only my servers since there will be a mix of public/private IP addressing.

Right now I have `restrict 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap` which will restrict the local subnet each NTP is on.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you do what you've described above:

```
restrict 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
```

for each subnet or IP address you want to serve, then allow your servers (ie, those machines from whom you get your time) slightly less privilege:

```
restrict 128.118.25.3 noquery nomodify notrap nopeer
restrict 130.88.202.49 noquery nomodify notrap nopeer
restrict 128.59.59.177 noquery nomodify notrap nopeer
restrict 2a01:8000:0:4::123:123 noquery nomodify notrap nopeer
```

and then explicitly deny everyone else:

```
restrict default ignore
```

Note that this is incompatible with the use of pool servers, since those will change each time NTP restarts.  If you want to completely ignore the rest of the world, you will need to make arragnements to use specific NTP servers so you can list their addresses; ISPs often provide servers for this purpose.  If you must use pool servers, then don't have specific entries for your time servers, and instead change the "rest of the world" line to

```
restrict default noquery nomodify notrap nopeer
```